# Learning HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css

I am learning HTML and CSS. I am using the book Head First HTML with CSS & XHTML. I am able to get the HTML code to work just fine; however, when I try to get code with css in it to work when I open it up in the browser it looks like all the css was just ignored and it isn't formatted in any way. Here is the code I am working with.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Starbuzz Coffee</title>
        <style type=”text/css”>
            body {
                background-color: #d2b48c;
                margin-left: 20%;
                margin-right: 20%;
                border: 1px dotted gray;
                padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
                font-family: sans-serif;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Starbuzz Coffee Beverages</h1>
        <h2>House Blend, $1.49</h2>
        <p>A smooth, mild blend of coffees from Mexico, Bolivia and Guatemala.</p>
        <h2>Mocha Caffe Latte, $2.35</h2>
        <p>Espresso, steamed milk and chocolate syrup.</p>
        <h2>Cappuccino, $1.89</h2>
        <p>A mixture of espresso, steamed milk and milk foam.</p>
        <h2>Chai Tea, $1.85</h2>
        <p>A spicy drink made with black tea, spices, milk and honey.</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It might be that you're using a different character encoding for your quotation marks around `text/css`.

Comment: Looks nice and styled to me in [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hcLsum7y/).

Comment: It's about your quotes: ””
Should be: ""

Comment: Yeah I copied from a pdf and it copied the wrong quotation marks, thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Use proper quotes. Change `<style type=”text/css”>` to `<style type="text/css">`.

Answer (score 3):

What are you using to edit the code? It seems that your editor is changing what you type, or you might have copied code from somewhere where someone had that problem.

You have typographic quotation marks around the type attribute value in the style tag, those should be regular quotation marks.

Change this:

```
<style type=”text/css”>
```

to:

```
<style type="text/css">
```

Comment: I am using notepad and opening with chrome

Comment: @4mad3u5: Notepad works fine. If you had used something like MS Word to edit the code, that could have substituted the characters.

Comment: I copied from a pdf and when I copy it copies the wrong quote mark

Comment: @4mad3u5: Aha, that sounds reasonable. The PDF is likely created with a program that substitutes the quotation marks. A PDF is usually used for typographic text, not so often HTML code.

Answer (score 2):

Just remove type=”text/css” in the style tag.
type="text/css" is obsolete.

Comment: what do want to achieve by removing?

Comment: type="text/css" is obsolete since HTML5

Comment: sure..but previous was misleading...I just upvoted:-)

Comment: ummm when I removed it completely it doesn't work

Comment: <style>Your CSS goes here...</style> should work ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You want to change you CSS to

```
 <style>
  body {
  background-color: #d2b48c;
  margin-left: 20%;
  margin-right: 20%;
  border: 1px dotted gray;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  }
 </style>
```

That will fix you problem. You don't need the text/css.

This is because what you are doing above is inline CSS. You have it situated next to the HTML itself.

You would use "text/css" if you were linking to a separate CSS stylesheet where your CSS code was stored.

In which case it would look like the below.

```
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
</head>
```

There is a helpful link [here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp) Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

1. Change :

   type=”text/css” to type="text/css" in style tag.
2. Or simply remove type=”text/css” from style tag and use :

   ```
   <style>
       body {
           background-color: #d2b48c;
           margin-left: 20%;
           margin-right: 20%;
           border: 1px dotted gray;
           padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
           font-family: sans-serif;
       }
   </style>
   ```

Either of them will work.